# Problema no formato da data (mm/dd/yyyy)

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

Tenho uma aplicação ASP.NET Core e não consigo achar uma solução para o meu problema de formato de data. A minha aplicação, está publicada em um servidor da Microsoft Azure, que provavelmente está nos EUA (embora apareça sul do Brasil) e tem me causado esses transtornos.

Eu tenho uma outra aplicação em MVC5 que também está publicado no Azure e que não me da problema, eu simplesmente defini a cultura no web.config e foi resolvido o problema da data.

```
  <system.web>
    <globalization culture="pt-BR" />
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
  </system.web>
```

No ASP.NET Core, achei alguns posts sobre definição da cultura no startup.cs, mas já tentei algumas coisas sem sucesso. Alguém já passou por essa situação e sabe como eu resolvo o meu problema?

Algo que eu já tentei:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            //Setting Culture

            services.AddLocalization(options => options.ResourcesPath = "Resources");

            services.AddMvc().AddViewLocalization().AddDataAnnotationsLocalization();

            //services.AddScoped<LanguageActionFilter>();

            services.Configure<RequestLocalizationOptions>(
               options =>
               {
                   var supportedCultures = new List<CultureInfo>
                       {
                            new CultureInfo("pt-BR")

                       };

                   options.DefaultRequestCulture = new RequestCulture(culture: "pt-BR", uiCulture: "pt-BR");
                   options.SupportedCultures = supportedCultures;
                   options.SupportedUICultures = supportedCultures;
               });
```

**EDITADO:**
Não tinha deixado claro o meu problema... Apesar de eu colocar a informação acima no statup.cs as datas no meu Controller fica mm/dd/yyyy, ou seja, tenho um calendário na aplicação, o usuário escolhe a data no Picker e manda gravar com a data 20/08/2017 e da erro, mas se ele preencher a data 08/20/2017 funciona.

Na minha VIEW:

```
  @*MODAL REGISTRAR AGENDA*@
    <div class="modal fade" id="ModalAgenda" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="ModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg lg-effect-10" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <h3 class="modal-title">Registro de Compromisso</h3>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <div class="row no-padding">
                        <div class="col-sm-12" style="padding-left: 0; padding-right: 0;">
                            <div class="panel">
                                <div class="panel-body">
                                    <div class="row">
                                        <div class="form-group col-sm-4">
                                            <label>Tipo</label>
                                            <select class="form-control" name="tipoAgenda" id="tipoAgenda">
                                                <option selected="selected">SELECIONE</option>
                                                <option value="1">CONTATO</option>
                                                <option value="2">VISITA</option>
                                                <option value="3">REUNIAO</option>
                                                <option value="4">TOUR COMERCIAL</option>
                                                <option value="5">APRESENTAÇÃO</option>
                                                <option value="6">ASSEMBLÉIA</option>
                                            </select>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="form-group col-sm-8">
                                            <label class="control-label">Título</label>
                                            <input class="form-control" name="Titulo" id="Titulo" data-val="true" />
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="row">
                                        <div class="form-group col-sm-12">
                                            <label class="control-label">Descrição</label>
                                            <textarea class="form-control" name="Descricao" id="Descricao" data-val="true" rows="6"></textarea>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="row">
                                        <div class="form-group  col-sm-4" id="data1">
                                            <label class="control-label">Data</label>
                                            <div class="input-group date">
                                                <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i></span><input type="text" name="Data1" id="Data1" class="form-control">
                                            </div>
                                        </div>

                                        <div class="form-group col-sm-2">
                                            <label class="control-label">Hora Início</label>
                                            <div class="input-group clockpicker" data-autoclose="true">
                                                <input type="text" name="HoraInicio" id="HoraInicio" class="form-control">
                                                <span class="input-group-addon">
                                                    <span class="fa fa-clock-o"></span>
                                                </span>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="form-group col-sm-2">
                                            <label class="control-label">Hora Fim</label>
                                            <div class="input-group clockpicker" data-autoclose="true">
                                                <input type="text" name="HoraFim" id="HoraFim" class="form-control">
                                                <span class="input-group-addon">
                                                    <span class="fa fa-clock-o"></span>
                                                </span>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <br />
                                    <div class="row">
                                        <div class="form-group col-sm-2">
                                            <label class="control-label">Notificar</label>
                                            <input type="text" name="Notifica" id="Notifica" class="form-control" style="text-align:center" value="30" />
                                        </div>

                                        <div class="form-group col-sm-4">
                                            <label class="control-label">Antes do agendamento</label>
                                            <select class="form-control" name="tipoAlerta" id="tipoAlerta">
                                                <option selected="selected" value="1">MINUTOS</option>
                                                <option value="2">HORAS</option>
                                                <option value="3">DIAS</option>
                                            </select>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal">Cancelar</button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" onclick="GravaAgenda()">Gravar</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Mu Js que manda as informações para a Controller

```
function GravaAgenda() {

    var prospect = $("#IdProspect").val();
    var tipoagenda = $('#tipoAgenda option:selected').val();
    var titulo = $("#Titulo").val();
    var descricao = $("#Descricao").val();
    var data1 = $("#Data1").val();
    var horainicio = $("#HoraInicio").val();
    var horafim = $("#HoraFim").val();
    var notifica = $("#Notifica").val();
    var tipoalerta = $('#tipoAlerta option:selected').val();


    //Gravar
    var url = "/Agenda/GravaAgenda";

    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        datatype: "json",
        data: { 'prospect': prospect, 'tipoagenda': tipoagenda, 'titulo': titulo, 'descricao': descricao, 'data1': data1, 'horainicio': horainicio, 'horafim': horafim, 'notifica': notifica, 'tipoalerta': tipoalerta },
        type: "POST",
        success: function (data) {
            swal({ type: "success", title: "Gravado com sucesso!", timer: 2000, showConfirmButton: false });
            window.location.reload();
        }
    });
};
```

Meu Controller:

```
 public async Task GravaAgenda(string prospect, string tipoagenda, string titulo, string descricao, string data1, string horainicio, string horafim, string notifica, string tipoalerta)
        {
            var ageData = new AgendaData();
            var user = await _userManager.GetUserAsync(User);
            string usuario = user.Id;
            int empresa = user.IdEmpresa;
            int Idprospect = Convert.ToInt32(prospect);
            int minutos = 0;           
            var tipoAgenda = TipoAgenda.Contato;

            switch (tipoalerta)
            {
                case "3":
                    minutos = Convert.ToInt32(notifica) * 24 * 60;
                    break;
                case "2":
                    minutos = Convert.ToInt32(notifica) * 24;
                    break;
                case "1":
                    minutos = Convert.ToInt32(notifica);
                    break;
            }
            switch (tipoagenda)
            {
                case "1":
                    tipoAgenda = TipoAgenda.Contato;
                    break;
                case "2":
                    tipoAgenda = TipoAgenda.Visita;
                    break;
                case "3":
                    tipoAgenda = TipoAgenda.Reuniao;
                    break;
                case "4":
                    tipoAgenda = TipoAgenda.Tour;
                    break;
                case "5":
                    tipoAgenda = TipoAgenda.Apresentacao;
                    break;
                case "6":
                    tipoAgenda = TipoAgenda.Assembleia;
                    break;
            }

            var dataInicio = Convert.ToDateTime(data1 + " " + horainicio);
            var dataFim = Convert.ToDateTime(data1 + " " + horafim);
            var dataAlerta = dataInicio.AddMinutes(-minutos);

            await ageData.GravaAgenda(Idprospect, usuario, titulo, descricao, dataInicio, dataFim, dataAlerta, tipoAgenda, empresa);
            await new ProspectLogData().RegitroContato(Idprospect, usuario, "REGISTRO DE AGENDAMENTO DO PROSPECT.", "8");
            RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
```

Minha camada de gravação no Banco

```
   public async Task GravaAgenda(int Idprospect, string usuario, string titulo, string descricao, DateTime dataInicio, DateTime dataFim, DateTime dataAlerta, TipoAgenda tipoAgenda, int empresa)
        {
            using (var db = new CRMContext())
            {
                var agenda = new Agenda();
                agenda.IdProspect = Idprospect;
                agenda.IdUsuario = usuario;
                agenda.Titulo = titulo.ToUpper();
                agenda.Descricao = descricao.ToUpper();
                agenda.DataInicio = dataInicio;
                agenda.DataFim = dataFim;
                agenda.DataAlerta = dataAlerta;
                agenda.Criado = DateTime.Now;
                agenda.TipoAgenda = tipoAgenda;
                agenda.IdEmpresa = empresa;
                db.Agenda.Add(agenda);
                await db.SaveChangesAsync();
            }
        }
```

Comment: Qual é o problema, faltou dizer isso ??? relate o problema porque, a culture é assim mesmo no AspNetCore!

Comment: Tipo: onde dá o problema! e que momento acontece o problema?

Comment: Obrigado @Virgilio editei o post, o problema é na transição da View para o controller. Tenho um picker que ta configurado corretamente para rt-BR, o usuário escolhe a data, por exemplo hoje dia 04/09/2017 mas ao mandar para o controller ele troca o formato e grava no banco 09/04/2017.

Comment: Se pode colocar a View e o Controller?

Comment: Postei a View e a Controller. Uso essa mesma estrutura em tres projetos diferentes MVC5 acho que não estou conseguindo me acertar com o Statup e o json config.

Comment: Está errado o conceito, porque não utiliza a classe corretamente e outra se os campos tem tipo de dados definidos se não deve colocar string data e sim datetime data, teste isso.

Comment: Utilize para conversão de datas https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/w2sa9yss(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Não ta errado @Virgilio me acredite, eu tenho centenas de estruturas como esta nas minhas aplicações. Note que é string pq vem de um JS, e depois é convertido para Datetime no Controller. O mesmo acontecia com as minhas aplicações MVC5. No entanto como não estou sabendo configurar corretamente a cultura para pt-BR no aspet Core, quando da conversão, está sendo convertida a string para "mm/dd/yyyy". É exatamente esse o meu problema, definir a CULTURA "pt-BR" no Startup.cs.

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/65074/discussion-between-virgilio-novic-and-rogerio-azevedo).

Comment: @RogerioAzevedo O VirgilioNovic está certo, isso é completamente errado. Isso funcionar, mas não deveria ser feito assim.

Comment: Obrigado @LINK o Virgílio falou comigo no Chat, ele me sugeriu que eu faça um binding na model como o Scafolding faz. Nesse caso eu não utilizei assim, por ser uma tabela diferente sendo chamada por um Modal, não tenho certeza se dá para usar o Bind da mesma forma pois não posso instanciar 2 models na mesma View mas vou tentar com toda certeza. Eu ainda preciso resolver o problema de cultura da aplicação, pois qualquer converto to datetime, vai converter para mm/dd/yyyy.

Comment: @Virgilio, deu certo a sua sugestão do parseExact utilizando o provider Culture, por enquanto resolve meu problema. Vou reescrever o controller fazendo o Binding como você sugeriu, mas como eu preciso do convert para somar String Data + String Time vou continuar com o problema apesar do Binding. Ainda vou precisar de alguem que saiba definir a cultura no AspNet Core.

Comment: é assim mesmo que define a Cultura, não tem outra forma @RogerioAzevedo e talvez seja configuração do servidor.

Comment: @Virgilio e LINK muito obrigado mesmo pela dicas de vocês, vou considerar alterar a forma que eu estou bindando a model. Talvez eu tenha que criar uma nova ViewModel, já que, como eu falei, a gravação da agenda é chamada em um Modal dentro de uma outra Model. Se assim é a forma correta, vou aprender a fazer assim! Quanto ao problema de cultura no aspnet core, finalmente encontrei a solução, e vou postar aqui para ajudar outros colegas que precisem da mesma coisa.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finalmente! Eu já tava ficando louco com esse problema! Com a dica do colega @Virgilio eu fiz um workaround e consegui evitar que na conversão da string para Datetime, a data saísse de "dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss" para "mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss" pois o projeto ta publicado nos EUA.

**Fixar Cultura no CONTROLLER**

```
string data1 
string horainicio 
string horafim

var ageData = new AgendaData();
var user = await _userManager.GetUserAsync(User);
string usuario = user.Id;
int empresa = user.IdEmpresa;
int Idprospect = Convert.ToInt32(prospect);
int minutos = 0;           
var tipoAgenda = TipoAgenda.Contato;

var provider = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;
provider = new CultureInfo("pt-BR");            
string formato = "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm";

var dataInicio = DateTime.ParseExact(data1 + " " + horainicio, formato, provider);
var dataFim = DateTime.ParseExact(data1 + " " + horafim, formato, provider);           
var dataAlerta = dataInicio.AddMinutes(-minutos);
```

Fixando a cultura no Controller eu resolveria parte do problema, pois sempre teria que fazer a mesma coisa em todos os Controllers, eu precisava fixar a cultura para o projeto. E consegui da seguinte forma.

**Aquivo Startp.cs**

```
   public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory, CRMContext context)
        {
            loggerFactory.AddConsole(Configuration.GetSection("Logging"));
            loggerFactory.AddDebug();

            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
                app.UseDatabaseErrorPage();
                app.UseBrowserLink();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
            }

            //Fixar Cultura para pt-BR
            RequestLocalizationOptions localizationOptions = new RequestLocalizationOptions
            {
                SupportedCultures = new List<CultureInfo> { new CultureInfo("pt-BR") },
                SupportedUICultures = new List<CultureInfo> { new CultureInfo("pt-BR") },
                DefaultRequestCulture = new RequestCulture("pt-BR")
            };
            app.UseRequestLocalization(localizationOptions);
            //----------------------------------------------------------------------------------

            app.UseStaticFiles();
            app.UseIdentity();

            // Add external authentication middleware below. To configure them please see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=532715

            app.UseMvc(routes =>
            {
                routes.MapRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
            });

            context.Database.EnsureCreated();
        }
```

Comment: Pode marcar sua própria resposta como aceita :-)

Comment: Opa, tinha me esquecido, obrigado @vnbrs